# Bullets and Enumeration in meetingmins, hiddenitems

Tags: enumerate, itemize, meetingmins

I am relatively new to using the `meetingmins` class, and overall I'm very pleased with it. However, the `hiddenitems` default to being enumerated and sometimes I want them to be bulleted. Can someone tell me whether this is possible? (I know how to change the non-hidden items back and forth using `itemize` and `enumerate`.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

- The good news: `meetingmins` uses the `enumitem` package!
- The bad  news: The class author does not really use `enumitem` features to make it configurable :-(

This is the original definition of `hiddenitem` (being behind an `\@ifundefined` statement, so more caution has to follow)

```
\newenvironment{hiddenitems}{%
  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0.5in]
}{%
  \end{enumerate}%
}
```

This is changed to

```
\renewenvironment{hiddenitems}{%
  \begin{enumerate}[label={\textbullet},leftmargin=0.5in]
}{%
  \end{enumerate}%
}
```

`label={\textbullet}` will use the bullets then.

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,agenda]{meetingmins}

%\usepackage{xpatch}


\setcommittee{Department of Instruction}
\setmembers{
\chair{B.~Smart},
B.~Brave,
D.~Claire,
B.~Gone
}
\setdate{October 5, 2011}


%\let\orighiddenitemsstart\hiddenitems
%\let\orighiddenitemsend\endhiddenitems % Not needed here

\renewenvironment{hiddenitems}{%
  \begin{enumerate}[label={\textbullet},leftmargin=0.5in]
}{%
  \end{enumerate}%
}


\begin{document}


\maketitle
\section{Announcements}
\begin{hiddenitems}
\item
The dean is coming today.
\item
The dean has canceled.
\end{hiddenitems}
\section{Committee Reports}
\subsection{College-wide Committees}
\subsubsection{Library}
The library still has books that no one has read.
\subsubsection{Curriculum {\rm (D.~Claire)}}
\begin{hiddensubitems}
\item
There is widespread interest in reforming
the curriculum.
\item
Unfortunately, no one seems interested
in participating on the curriculum
reform committee.
\end{hiddensubitems}
\subsection{Department Committees}
\subsubsection{Personnel}
\subsubsection{Assistant Professor Search}
\section{Old Business}
\begin{items}
\item
\priormins
\end{items}
\section{New Business}
\begin{items}
\item
We will teach classes next semester.
\item
We will do research next semester.
\end{items}
\vspace{1em}
\nextmeeting{Wednesday, October 19, at 3:00}
\end{document}
```

**New version**

A starter: Renew the environments `hiddenitems` etc. and add an optional `*` argument to it. See the differences in the output.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{meetingmins}

\usepackage{xparse}


\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{@agenda}{%
  \RenewDocumentEnvironment{hiddenitems}{sO{}}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
      \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbullet,leftmargin=0.5in,#2]
      }{%
        \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0.5in,#2]%
        }%
      }{%
      \end{enumerate}%
    }
  }{%
    \let\hiddenitems\emptysection%
  }


\@ifundefined{@agenda}{% minutes
  \RenewDocumentEnvironment{hiddensubitems}{sO{}}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
      \begin{enumerate}[label=\textasteriskcentered,leftmargin=1in,#2]
      }{%
        \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1in,#2]
      }%
    }{%
      \end{enumerate}
    }}{% agenda only
      \let\hiddensubitems\emptysection
    }%

\@ifundefined{@agenda}{% minutes
  \RenewDocumentEnvironment{hiddensubsubitems}{sO{}}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
      \begin{enumerate}[label={$\triangleright$},leftmargin=1in,#2]
      }{%
        \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1in,#2]
      }%
    }{%
      \end{enumerate}
    }}{% agenda only
      \let\hiddensubsubitems\emptysection
    }%


\makeatother




\setcommittee{Department of Instruction}
\setmembers{
\chair{B.~Smart},
B.~Brave,
D.~Claire,
B.~Gone
}
\setdate{October 5, 2011}


\let\orighiddenitemsstart\hiddenitems
\let\orighiddenitemsend\endhiddenitems



\begin{document}


\maketitle
\section{Announcements}
\begin{hiddenitems}*
\item
The dean is coming today.
\item
The dean has canceled.
\end{hiddenitems}
\section{Committee Reports}
\subsection{College-wide Committees}
\subsubsection{Library}
The library still has books that no one has read.
\subsubsection{Curriculum {\rm (D.~Claire)}}
\begin{hiddensubitems}*
\item
There is widespread interest in reforming
the curriculum.
\item
Unfortunately, no one seems interested
in participating on the curriculum
reform committee.
\end{hiddensubitems}


\begin{hiddensubsubitems}*
\item First
\end{hiddensubsubitems}

\begin{hiddensubsubitems}
\item First -- non starred
\end{hiddensubsubitems}


\subsection{Department Committees}
\subsubsection{Personnel}
\subsubsection{Assistant Professor Search}
\section{Old Business}
\begin{items}
\item
\priormins
\end{items}
\section{New Business}
\begin{items}
\item
We will teach classes next semester.
\item
We will do research next semester.
\end{items}
\vspace{1em}
\nextmeeting{Wednesday, October 19, at 3:00}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Just to clarify, it looks like you're redefining the hiddenitems environment entirely - am I correct that this would make all hiddenitems bulleted, but not really allow me to switch back and forth?  What if I want the hiddenitems bulleted in some parts of the minutes and numbered in others? Asking too much?

Comment: @user38869: I know, I know, but my time is limited -- It takes time to improve this weird feature of the class! And for the moment: Yes, you're asking too much, considering the fact that you provided nothing to start with ;-)

Comment: I certainly appreciate your time and assistance, but I fear you may have misunderstood me slightly.  My original question was simply whether this was possible, not actually how to do it (though I do appreciate the code you wrote out).  I suppose I was simply still curious whether it would be asking too much of the software to expect that flexibility. I apologise if it seemed like I was asking you to write it for me.

Comment: @user38869: Yes, it is possible

Comment: Thank you again, I certainly do appreciate the nudge in the right direction!

Comment: @user38869: I nevertheless provided a better solution where you can decide what to use: `\begin{hiddenitems}*` or omit the `*`. An even better solution would use `\newlist` definitions from `enumitem`. I think, the author of the class should be contacted ;-)